# Making a custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The goal is to create a URL like this for a GET, REST API:

```
/manager/someID/report
example: /manager/2/report
```

I can get it to show in rake routes if  do it this way:

```
get 'manager/:id/report', to: 'report#show'
```

But in some weblogs I read, thats the way unskilled developers write their routes! and looks like the better way is to use "nested resources" so I am banging my head over desk to get nested resources working the same way...but no success

this is what I have written so far:

```
  resources :manager, only: [:show] do
    resources :report, only: [:show], controller: 'report' do
     member do
       ## WAT ?!
     end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to consider reading different blogs if they're calling routes like that "unskilled".

What you proposed is actually fine considering it's a non-standard RESTful route, and maybe even preferable in some cases. If you want an alternative approach, you have a couple different options. I don't think any one is more right than the other, but I prefer the first because it takes up less vertical space.

```
resources :manager, only: [:show] do
  get 'report' => 'report#show', on: :member
end
```

or

```
resources :manager, only: [:show] do
  member do
    get 'report' => 'report#show'
  end
end
```

Comment: is this way of nesting, the ones you have and the even the second non-working one that I had,  are these really meant for stuff that have a has_many, belongs_to relation?  like Article and Comments...  Because in my case the nature of "manager" and "report" is not really like that at all . So still would be viable to do it with nested? or my own one liner route was good too?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a right or wrong answer to those questions. I've been using Rails for a while and they all seem valid to me. The only change I would probably make would be to pluralize the report controller name so it follows Rails' conventions.